# Convert Devexpress control to UIElement

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, devexpress, uielement

I have a program who on drag and drop generate XAML code and I use this to create new form from this template.
It work if i use standard WPF control, but if I use devexpress wpf control get a error convert to UIElement
error:

**No matching constructor found on type
'DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.ButtonEditPropertyProvider'. You can use the
 Arguments or FactoryMethod directives to construct this type.'**

code:

```
private UIElement ExtractElement(IDataObject obj)
{
        string xamlString = obj.GetData("FluidKit") as string;
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xamlString));
        UIElement elt = XamlReader.Load(reader) as UIElement;

        return elt;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have incompatible references. Update the references, this should work.